# Nagios Monitoring for changing server threshold

Tags: nagios

I have a server that is monitored by Nagios. The nagios is constantly show high CPU usage but at this usage, my Server is working fine. Is it possible to increase the CPU check threshold, I mean like it will show warning only if CPU usage reaches 60% ?

Graphical View of exiting settings shows this:

$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 30 -c $ARG1$ 
CheckCounter -a "Counter:mutex=\Objects\Mutexes" ShowAll MaxWarn=500 MaxCrit=1000

Comment: This is a Windows box, running nsclient++ yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can increase the CPU threshold , what you need to do is to make changes in nrpe.cfg file on your server which you are monitoring through Nagios

/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg usually this file on RPM based servers.

Comment: This isn't going to help him, since he's talking about a Windows box

Comment: No no, my nagois server is on Linux. By graphical I meant the user interface when I open on Browser. @abhishek anand, I will do this and check if it works.